# Logitech Z506 connected to 2 devices

Tags: audio, connection, speakers

I wonder If I can have my Logitech Z506 connected to 2 devices - 1. my monitor (for xbox gaming) and 2. my desktop PC (unfortunately I can't connect my PC with the monitor using HDMI - no sound transfer then, so PC has to be directly connected to Z506). Wonder to know if that would work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The Z506 has multiple inputs, making such a setup easy, so long as you have the right sorts of outputs from your various devices.

This is from the device page on the Logitech site (http://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/surround-sound-speaker-z506):

> Multiple inputs
>
> You’ve got the flexibility to set up your system the way you want to.
>   Connect your PC, PS3™, Xbox 360®, Wii®, iPod®, DVD player, and more.